# PHP not outputting the onclick in anchor tag

Tags: shortcode

I have this plugin code

```
function add_neori_social_share_buttons_icons($atts){
    global $post;

    $url = get_permalink($post->ID);
    $url = esc_url($url);

    $media = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID));
    $media = esc_url($media);

    $description = get_the_title($post->ID);
    $description = esc_html($description);

    $html = $html . "<a target='_blank' href='http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=" . $url . "'><div class='icon-social-facebook col'></div></a>";

    $html = $html . "<a target='_blank' href='https://twitter.com/share?url=" . $url . "'><div class='icon-social-twitter col'></div></a>";

    $html = $html . "<a target='_blank' href='mailto:?subject=I wanted to share this post with you from&body=" . $url . "'><i class='fa fa-envelope-o'></i></a>";

    $html = $html . "<a onclick='myFunction()' href='JavaScript:void(0)'><i class='fa fa-print'></i></a>";

    $html = $html . "</div>";

    return $content = $content . $html;
}

add_shortcode('neori-social-share-icons', 'add_neori_social_share_buttons_icons');
```

it displays four icons in the post section but for the last print icon. It doesn't out put the onclick attribute of anchor tag no matter what I do.

Here is the post URL for that 4 icons.

http://mandybright.promogent.com/victims-of-the-border-husband-of-u-s-citizen-wife-disappears-after-desert-crossing/

Comment: Would it not make more sense to add an ID or html class then do something like `jQuery(".onprint").click( ... )` in an enqueued javascript file? `onClick` handlers are bad practice, and 100% avoidable, you shouldn't need to put javascript directly in a shortcode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think WP is stripping the onclick out of the content. You shouldn't really use inline onclick anyway.

Give the link an ID and then add an on click in your JS.  Something like this...

```
jQuery('#myLink').click(function() {
    ... Your myFunction() code
});
```

Comment: Thank you it worked out